# pyqt5 calling function does not give same results

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to develop a GUI to show my robot and obstacles around it. I created a class GUI and it has a member function showObstacle to show obstacle. Since I want to keep all the obstacles in place, I create new obstacle object in a vector to store all the objects.

I called this function in class's **init** function to test and it was successful.

But when I call this function in different class, it doesn't show the obstacles on the GUI window. In class TCP_Connection (where I get information about the robot), I created myGui class and I called showObstacle function.

After debugging, it turns out it creates the Obstacle Objects whenever it is called, but it doesn't display it on the window

```
#this is file 1, GUI Class
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from pynput import keyboard

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, OtherWindow):

        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100,100,440,800)
        self.setWindowTitle("New GUI Interface Window")
        self.currentState = 0
        self.obstCounter = 0
        self.d = []

        #testing showObstacle
        self.showObstacle(205, 305) #this works
        self.showObstacle(210,315)  #this also works
        self.show()

    def showObstacle(self, Obs_x, Obs_y):
        self.obstImage = QtGui.QImage('obsta_edited.png')
        self.pixmap_obst = QtGui.QPixmap(self.obstImage)
        self.d.append("O{0}".format(self.obstCounter))
        self.d[self.obstCounter] = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.d[self.obstCounter].setPixmap(self.pixmap_obst)
        self.d[self.obstCounter].move(Obs_x, Obs_y)
        self.d[self.obstCounter].adjustSize()
        self.obstCounter += 1

        print(self.d)
        print("Obstacle Run")
```

this is the calling class

```
from myGUI import App
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QLabel,QLineEdit, QHBoxLayout,QVBoxLayout,QMainWindow,QPushButton, QFrame, QDesktopWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.Qt import QStackedLayout
import sys, random

class TCP_Communication:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.openWindow()

    def openWindow(self):

        self.window = QMainWindow()
        self.myGui = App(self.window)
        self.myGui.showObstacle(215, 320)
        self.stacked_layout = QStackedLayout()
        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.myGui)

    def tcp_showObstacle(self,x,y):
        self.myGui.showObstacle(x,y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    tcp_com = TCP_Communication()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Edited : attached the result ; Suppose to show 4 obstacles but only shows 2

Edited2 : Code is executable now

[image: Suppose to show 4 obstacles but only shows 2]

Comment: what is `initUI`? 
Your code is complete? 
when you call openWindow()?

Comment: `initUI`  is for initializing bunch of UI-s that I need. The code is complete but I thought pasting every thing in the code would make it hard to read so I extracted parts that are directly relevant

Comment: It is good that you put a minimum code, but at the same time that code must be complete in the sense that it can be executed, and yours is not, please take the time and improve your example. :D

Comment: Sorry about that.. I edited the code so that code is now executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `QLabel`s are not showing, the main widget when displayed at the beginning makes your children show up, but after that it does not make them visible, as it is in your case, so your task is to call their method `show()` directly:

```
def showObstacle(self, Obs_x, Obs_y):
    pixmap_obst = QtGui.QPixmap('obsta_edited.png')
    self.d.append("O{0}".format(self.obstCounter))
    label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
    label.setPixmap(pixmap_obst)
    label.move(Obs_x, Obs_y)
    label.adjustSize()
    label.show() # <---show QLabel

    self.d[self.obstCounter] = label
    self.obstCounter += 1

    print(self.d)
    print("Obstacle Run")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I never actually learned pyQT before. I have a question tho. In your code how does label gets different obstacle objects? My thought process of developing showObstacle was that I have to create pixmap and label for each obstacle object. I am sorry I am confused.

Comment: I would also appreciate any resources if you could suggest for pyqt5.

Comment: @programing_is_hard 
I do not understand you, explain yourself better. On the other hand if you are doing some game I recommend using QGraphicsView with QGraphicsScene that handle shocks, movement, etc, QLabel is not suitable for that task.

Comment: does QLabel has to be created for each obstacle objects?

Comment: @programing_is_hard 
I do not understand you, that depends on your design and what you want to do, but I suppose so.